# .panel-default border color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I have a bootstrap default panel:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    ...
```

I want remove the border, but don't want to use additional class or id, etc..

Inspecting elements in chrome I see:

```
.panel-default {
    border-color: #ddd;
}
```

That's how it got this value assigned.
As I know I can overwrite css values by applying (at least) new values by same css selectors. My css file is imported after bootstrap file.

I tried:

```
.panel-default {
    border-color: none;
}
```

Does not work, but if I use:

```
.panel-default {
    border: none;
}
```

this works.

So `none` is not an acceptable value for `border-color`? or what a hack it might be? because if I assign none from `inspect element` feature of chrome it works.

Comment: If you want the border defined but no color, use `transparent`. the valid values are a color, transparent, initial, and inherit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes `none` is not a valid value of `border-color`, so you have to use `border: none` to remove it or `border-color: transparent` if you want to keep the border, but make it invisible.

The reason it works for chrome devtools is, that chrome is not applying invalid styles such as `border-color: none` and if you're changing the original style of your element, the style gets removed.